# PHP - array_multisort ? Sorting postal code (zip code)

Tags: php, postal-code, array-multisort

After calculating distances between two points using latitude and longitude, I've created an array which looks like this:

```
$enterprises = array();

//Ex.: Array ( [0] => Array ( [A0A0A0] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [A0A1A0] => 22.794344863539 ) 
for ($i=0; $i < count($cpEnterprise) ; $i++) {

        $enterprises[] = array($cpEnterprise[$i] => distance($actualCpLat, $actualCpLong, $businessLat[$i], $businessLong[$i], 'k'));

}
```

The main array contains the enterprises that is needed for a comparison with the actual postal codes inside it. POSTAL CODE => DISTANCE.

I need to sort those inner arrays by distance from the nearest to the farthest and I don't really understand how array_multisort works...

Comment: is there a reason you are doing `$enterprises[] = array($cpEnterprise[$i] => distance($actualCpLat, $actualCpLong, $businessLat[$i], $businessLong[$i], 'k'))` instead of `$enterprises[$cpEnterprise[$i]] = distance($actualCpLat, $actualCpLong, $businessLat[$i], $businessLong[$i], 'k')`? The second way would allow you to use [asort](http://www.php.net/asort).

Comment: @Orangepill well no actually good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to tackle this is to restructure your array and use asort

```
$enterprises = array();

//Ex.: Array ( [0] => Array ( [A0A0A0] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [A0A1A0] => 22.794344863539 ) 
for ($i=0; $i < count($cpEnterprise) ; $i++) {    
        $enterprises[$cpEnterprise[$i]] = distance($actualCpLat, $actualCpLong, $businessLat[$i], $businessLong[$i], 'k');

}
asort($enterprises);
```

Comment: it does work thanks! How come `asort($enterprises)` acts on distances instead of postal code?

Comment: asort sorts by the array values... if you wanted to sort by the postcode (the keys of the array) you would use ksort. And if you ever need them backwards arsort is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your sort situation to use `array_multisort`. I'll give my example, you might get some clues:

```
$products_count = array(
  2 => 10,
  5 => 20,
  0 => 13
)

$counts = array();

foreach($products_count as $k => $v)
{
  $counts[$k] = $v;
}

array_multisort($counts, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC, $products_count);
```

Result:

```
array(
  0 => 13,
  2 => 10,
  5 => 20
)
```

This is just an example on `array_multisort` and defiantly there are more better solutions and answers to your question.